# Apply REGEX to slugs only

Tags: javascript, regex, workbox

I am using the following regex to cache all html pages in my service worker running in a jekyll site that uses pretty permalinks (i.e. excludes "index.html" in favor of simply /slug/):

```
/^[^.]+$/
```

This works fine when running on localhost:4000, but on production, the ".com" part of the domain breaks this. How can I modify this to only look for matches in slugs?

**Edit:** demo here: https://regex101.com/r/Jao8W0/6

Comment: Maybe you want to match an optional `....com`? Try `/^([^.]+\.com\/)?[^.]+$/`

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. Gave it a try, but it doesn't seem to work. Ideally, the REGEX would be versatile enough that it would work both under staging and production conditions (i.e. localhost:4000 and domain.com)

Comment: I guess you can put it this way: `/(?:^|yourdomain\.com\/)?[^.]+$/`

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your regular expression, match either your domain name or localhost using `(domain\.com|localhost:\d+)`, then match any sequence of characters except dot (as you've done.)

```
^(domain\.com|localhost:\d+)[^.]+?$
```

The `(domain\.com|localhost:\d+)` bit translates to:

```
(            # start a group for capturing a match or selecting from alternate matches
domain\.com  # match the literal string "domain.com"
|            # or
localhost:   # match the literal string "localhost:"
\d+          # match a digit (\d) one or more times (+)
)            # end a group
```

Comment: Thanks, @Zak. For some reason, this only seems to work for localhost:400, but not for domain.com. You can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/Jao8W0/7 I guess the most elegant solution would for the expression to match anything after the first `/` except if it contains a `.` Thoughts?

Comment: @MLDR For testing a regex over multiple lines in regex101.com, you'll need to enable the global and multiline flags. :) eg. https://regex101.com/r/Jao8W0/8

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that is working fine for me in production and staging:

```
/\/[^.]+?$/
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/Jao8W0/11